# How to import contacts from gmail?

Tags: api, grails, google-api, gmail

I have an web app that needs to import contacts of user from there mail account. How to use the API for that.

I am using socialauth sdk(2.4) with GGTS IDE in windows 7.
Working fine till i login to my gmail account. But gets redirected to error.jsp.
I copied the code from " https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStartedWithGrails ".
Please help me.

Comment: I am using grails, so please help me with code. I am new to grails. I am trying many codes and other things for more than 2 months.

Answer (score 0):

Google contacts API can be used to retrieve contacts from the users gmail account.

To retrieve all of a user's contacts, send an authorized GET request to the following URL:

https://www.google.com/m8/feeds/contacts/{userEmail}/full
With the appropriate value in place of userEmail.

Here is the [link](https://developers.google.com/google-apps/contacts/v3/#retrieving_all_contacts) for documentation.

Comment: Using socialauth SDK for importing contacts.                          I get this error no matter what: Key in Request Token is null or blank . Is there any way to store value in key variable of request. I have copied the code from : "https://code.google.com/p/socialauth/wiki/GettingStartedWithYourOwnFramework" and replaced Client ID and secret .  PLEASE HELP ME.